# Get bitmap only from the visible part of a View

Tags: android, view, bitmap, overlay

Is it possible to create a bitmap only from the visible part of a View? 
I am using a listview, but its elements are taller than the screen, so when I get the DrawingCache from a childview I get a bitmap that is taller than the screen.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
overlayView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
overlayView.buildDrawingCache();
mViewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(overlayView.getDrawingCache());
overlayView.destroyDrawingCache();
overlayView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: did you tried with view.getDrawingRect(rect); and then rescaled bitmap you got from view.getDrawingCache();

Answer (score 0):

You can find size of visible part of your view and then create bitmap with needed size (from bitmap you already have).

use this [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)